# Проблема с отображением кастомизированного JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Всем привет!
Такая проблема: имеется примитивное диалоговое окно

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
"<html><head><style>body {background-color: #3b3b3b; }</style><meta charset='UTF-8'></head>" 
+ "<body><span style='line-height: 1.5';>"
+ "<center><b><font color='#de6909' size=8>Благодарности</font></b></center><p></p>"
+ "тут текст<p></p><p></p>"
+ "</font>" + "</span></body>" + "</html>",
"Благодарности", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Пытаюсь покрасить окно через UIManager:

```
UIManager UI=new UIManager();
UI.put("OptionPane.background",new ColorUIResource(59,59,59));
```

В результате получается вот это:

[image: То что получается]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как покрасить фон, который на скриншоте имеет белый цвет (рядом с кнопкой ОК)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В недрах `BasicOptionPaneUI`, который отвечает за внешний вид `JOptionPane` используются три `JPanel`, поэтому можно покрасить все так:

```
// метод put у UIManager - статический, создавать его экземпляр не нужно
UIManager.put( "OptionPane.background",new ColorUIResource(59,59,59) );
UIManager.put( "Panel.background",new ColorUIResource(59,59,59) );
```

Если цвет панелей во всей программе менять нельзя, можно сохранить старое значение `"Panel.background"` перед вызовом `showMessageDialog` и потом вернуть обратно, либо написать и зарегистрировать свою реализацию `BasicOptionPaneUI`.

Comment: Все получилось! Огромное спасибо!